# Text file to SQL

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssis

Can someone shed some light on how to proceed.

I have a requirement in which I have a text file in //Serveraddress-s//abc.txt in a server location, I need to import this to SQL Server table every time the file is changed and need to use it for reporting purposes.

What I am thinking is to create a SSIS package from SQL Server Import and Export Data and save the package and would like to use it in a Job which runs every day and the table is truncated and updated daily and I can use the data in the table for reporting.

Please advice if there are any other ways to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

> What I am thinking is to create a SSIS package from SQL Server Import
>   and Export Data and save the package and would like to use it in a Job
>   which runs every day and the table is truncated and updated daily and
>   I can use the data in the table for reporting.

This is how I would do it, as long as the file isn't millions of rows.